# Java indexOf returns -1

Tags: java

So I am reading in a line from a file, that looks like:

```
Snowman:286:355:10
```

And  this is the first part of the code I wrote to separate the data and place it into arrays.

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i<manyItems; i++)
                {
                    a = 0;

                    temp = scan.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(temp);

                    b = temp.indexOf(':');
                    System.out.println(b);

                    items[i] = temp.substring(a,b);
                    System.out.println(items[i]);
                    System.out.println(temp);

                    a = b;

                    System.out.println(temp);

                    b = temp.indexOf(a+1,':');
                    System.out.println(b);

                    rawX[i] = temp.substring(a+1,b);
                    System.out.println(rawX[i]);


                }
```

It separates "Snowman" places it into the array, however, when I try to find the second colon, indexOf() keeps returning -1. Does anyone know why it is not finding the second colon?

Answer (score 7):

You could save all that code and use [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split the line:

```
String[] parts = temp.split(":");
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you have the arguments backwards:

```
b = temp.indexOf(a+1,':');
```

Should be...

```
b = temp.indexOf(':', a+1);
```

From [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29):

> ```
> public int indexOf(int ch,
>                int fromIndex)
> ```

The first argument is the `ch`aracter, the second if the `fromIndex`.

Comment: True. Too bad this did not become a compile error (because the character is an int, too).

Comment: Because char and int are interchangeable.

Comment: This is spot on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String, int)

Answer (score 4):

Because you swapped the arguments of the indexOf call. It expects the character, then the index to start looking at. Remember that chars are ints, you're looking for the char 7 starting at the int value of ':'.

Comment: How does `substring` expect a character? Its signatures are `substring(int beginIndex)` and `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`. ?

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen: s/substring/indexOf/  fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method under `String` class that will handle the job for you. `Split(regEx pattern)` is what you may want to use. The following code will do the job you're trying to perform:

```
    String input = "Snowman:286:355:10";

    String tokens [] = input.split(":");

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        System.out.println(tokens[i]);
```