# Error launching my program, how can i fix it?

Tags: java

I have this assignment for my university https://cs1331.gitlab.io/fall2018/hw2/hw2-source-model.html. I wrote the code but when I run the program I get this message at the console :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 2
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3107)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1873)
    at homework1.SourceModel.main(SourceModel.java:127)
```

Here is my code for this assignment with comments :

```
 package homework1;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class SourceModel {

    //initialize variables so they can be accessed everywhere
    private String modelName;
    private int[][] characterCount;
    private double[] rowCount;
    private double[][] probability;

    /**
     * 
     * @param name takes the name of the corpus
     * @param fileName takes the filesName of corpus
     */
    public SourceModel(String name, String fileName) {
        modelName = name;
        characterCount = new int[26][26];
        rowCount = new double[26];
        probability = new double[26][26];
        System.out.println("Training " + name + "model...");

        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            String temp = "";

            //append all of the text
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                temp += scan.next();
            }

            //only keeps the letters and makes them lowercase
            temp = temp.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "").toLowerCase();
System.out.println(temp);
            //iterates trough each letter then puts the letters
            //sequence to the respective row and column

            for (int i = 0; i < (temp.length() - 1); i++) {
                char firstLetter = temp.charAt(i);
                char secondLetter = temp.charAt(i + 1);

                //index based on ASCII values
                characterCount[(int) firstLetter - 97][(int) secondLetter - 97]++;
                rowCount[(int) firstLetter - 97]++;
            }

            //calculates the probability by dividing the count
            //by the total counts in each row 
            for (int i = 0; i < probability.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < probability[i].length; j++) {
                    if (rowCount[i] == 0) {
                        rowCount[i] = 0.01;
                    }
                    probability[i][j] = (((double) characterCount[i][j]) / rowCount[i]);

                    if (probability[i][j] == 0) {
                        probability[i][j] = 0.01;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("done");

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return a string which contains the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return modelName;
    }

    /**
     * @return a string with the matrix 
     */
    public String toString() {
        String matrix = "";
        matrix += "";
        for (int i = 97; i < 123; i++) {
            matrix += "  ";
            matrix += (char) i;
        }
        matrix += ("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < probability.length; i++) {
            matrix += ((char) (i + 97) + " ");
            for (int j = 0; j < probability[i].length; j++) {
                matrix += String.format("%.2f", probability[i][j]);
                matrix += ("");
            }
            matrix += "\n";
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param test a set of letters to test
     * @return the probability for the word 
     */
    public double probability(String test) {
        test = test.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "").toLowerCase();
        double stringProbability = 1.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length() - 1; i++) {
            int firstIndex = (int) (test.charAt(i)) - 97;
            int secondIndex = (int) (test.charAt(i + 1)) - 97;
            stringProbability *= probability[firstIndex][secondIndex];
        }
        return stringProbability;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param args the command line arguments 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SourceModel[] models = new SourceModel[args.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
            models[i] = new SourceModel(args[i].substring(0, args[i].indexOf(".")), args[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Analyzing: " + args[args.length - 1]);
        double[] normalizedProbability = new double[args.length - 1];
        double sumProbability = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
            sumProbability += models[i].probability(args[args.length - 1]);
        }
        //normalize the probability in respect to the values given
        for (int i = 0; i < normalizedProbability.length; i++) {
            normalizedProbability[i] = models[i].probability(args[args.length - 1]) / sumProbability;
        }
        int highestIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print("Probability that test string is");
            System.out.printf("%9s: ", models[i].getName());
            System.out.printf("%.2f", normalizedProbability[i]);
            System.out.println("");
            if (normalizedProbability[i] > normalizedProbability[highestIndex]) {
                highestIndex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Test string is most likely " + models[highestIndex].getName() + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: please include your code

Comment: So "HipHop" and "Lisp" are languages now? lol

Comment: `substring(0, args[i].indexOf("."))` what if `args[i]` doesn't have `.`? `indexOf(".")` would return `-1` which is invalid value for `substring` as you see in exception message.

Comment: @Pshemo Beat me to it, I was just writing an answer pointing this out. Should this be answered or marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I am looking for duplicate. Ping me if you find it faster so I could vote on it.

Comment: @Pshemo Maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714446/java-indexof-returns-1)? I assume it would be pointless for both of us to mark this as a duplicate since you already wield Mjolnir for Java.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I am not sure. IMO it should contain explanation of what this exception means in relation to substring method (maybe it is faster to answer it...)

Comment: @Pshemo Looking at the text of the assignment again, I'm actually not convinced that that's the root cause of the problem. The assignment states that all of the file names should have a `.` in them, so this shouldn't be happening in the first place - there must be a problem with one of the command line parameters.

Comment: I'm actually going to vote +1 on this because the root cause of the bug ends up being non-obvious.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why remove the code from the question? Granted, the problem ends up being the command line parameters, but if anything I'd leave the code in and add the sample of the command line parameters so that the answers make sense if anyone runs into a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already pointed this out, but for this line:

```
models[i] = new SourceModel(args[i].substring(0, args[i].indexOf(".")), args[i]);
```

the `substring` method is apparently causing the problem because `indexOf` returns -1 if the `.` isn't found.

In this case, though, the code actually isn't the problem, since the assignment states that you can assume that the file names are of the form `<source-name>.corpus`. That being said, really, *all* of the command line parameters should have a `.` in them, so this shouldn't be happening.

I'd check to see what command line parameters you're passing. One guess I have is that you might have a file name with a space in it or something. For example, if you passed `English GB.corpus`, then this would show up as 2 separate arguments (one of which doesn't have a `.`).

**Edit:** As @Pshemo pointed out in the comments, if you have a file name that has a space in it, you can just put it in quotes so that it'll be interpreted as a single command line parameter - for example, instead of `English GB.corpus`, write `"English GB.corpus"`. That'll prevent the exception.

Comment: In case of file like `English GB.corpus` surround it with quotes "English GB.corpus" while passing it as command line argument to ensure that console will see it as single argument.

Comment: I put it in quotes but now it writes on the console Exception in thread "main" Analyzing: cdr.”
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at homework1.SourceModel.main(SourceModel.java:138)

Comment: @GabrielaI.Haras Which line is 138?

Comment: sumProbability += models[i].probability(args[args.length-1]);

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the command line parameter that you're passing?

Comment: “My other car is a cdr.”

Comment: Isn't the model assuming that the command line parameter is a file name (rather than the actual corpus body)? Or is that the argument to the `probability` method?

Comment: Running Your Program
Sample runs from the command line:
$ java SourceModel *.corpus "If you got a gun up in your waist please don't shoot up the place (why?)"

Comment: @GabrielaI.Haras I see that in the assignment now - in that case, if the first argument is something like `*.corpus`, you should search the directory where you're storing the corpus files for all files with that extension and then use the results of the search to initialize your models (rather than looping over all of the command line parameters and treating all of them as files).

Comment: @GabrielaI.Haras https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694385/getting-the-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder

Comment: Thanks! How can i search the directory to find all the corpus files?

Comment: Thanks i see now your answer, sorry

Comment: @halfer Yeah, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Possibly took unreasonable umbrage at the question edits? I dunno. Just a few days ago, I had a 1k user ragequit (deleted their whole account) because a mod decision didn't go their way. Everyone just needs a nice cup of tea... `:=)`

Comment: @halfer It seems unreasonable to remove the code to me - the q&a doesn’t make sense without it.

Answer (score 0):

In your main method, you have:

```
args[i].indexOf(".")
```

The dot (.) is not found so it returns -1.

You try to create a substring:

```
models[i] = new SourceModel(args[i].substring(0, args[i].indexOf(".")), args[i]);
```

But since `args[i].indexOf(".")` is invalid, it throws an exception.

What you can do is check if the dot (.) exists, if yes continue:

```
if(args[i].contains(".")){
models[i] = new SourceModel(args[i].substring(0, args[i].indexOf(".")), args[i]);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Can you print the args[i] to the console and show us the output?

Comment: @GabrielaI.Haras "but it even has a dot" what makes you think so? Please notice that with `for (int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++)` you are iterating and testing all arguments except last one. Is dot present at all of those arguments?